# Why don't these names with external linkage denote the same entity?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, linkage

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int a;
void address_of_a(void) {
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;
}

namespace N {
    int a;
    void address_of_a(void) {
        std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    }   
};

int main(void) {
    address_of_a();
    N::address_of_a();
    return 0;
}
```

**The global namespace and named namespace `N` are given external linkage** because 3.5 [basic.link] paragraph 4 from *N4567* says that

> An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage. **All other namespaces have external linkage**...

Furthermore, **`::a` and `N::a` are also given external linkage** because they are not applicable to 3.5 [basic.link] paragraph 3,

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of
>
> - a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared static; or,
> - a variable of non-volatile const-qualified type that is neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to have external linkage; or
> - a data member of an anonymous union.

but to 3.5 [basic.link] paragraph 4,

> ... A name having namespace scope **that has not been given internal linkage above** has the same linkage as the enclosing namespace if it is the name of
>
> - a variable; or
> - ...

which means to say that **they inherit the same linkage(=external linkage) as the global namespace and `N`**. In conclusion, **they shall denote the same entity** because 3.5 [basic.link] paragraph 9 says that

> Two names that are the same (Clause 3) and that are declared in different scopes shall denote the same variable, function, type, enumerator, template or namespace if
>
> - **both names have external linkage** or both names have internal linkage and are declared in the same translation unit; and
> - ...

However, they seem to denote different entities because their addresses didn't coincide. Why is that?

Comment: What about the line just after your last quote? (Note the _and_ right after what you quoted.)

Comment: @Mat `::a` and `N::a` are definitely declared in a single translation unit.

Comment: But both ::a and N::a are declared in the same, global, scope...why would you expect paragraph 9 to apply?

Comment: I'm talking about §3.5/9, says nothing about translation units

Comment: @JimLewis Aren't they declared in different scopes? `::a` is declared in the global namespace and `N::a` is declared in `N`.

Comment: @Mat I was mistaken. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the second bullet.

> Two names that are the same (Clause 3) and that are declared in different scopes shall denote the same variable, function, type, enumerator, template or namespace if
>
> - both names have external linkage or else both names have internal linkage and are declared in the same translation unit; **and**
> - **both names refer to members of the same namespace** or to members, not by inheritance, of the same class; and
> - when both names denote functions, the parameter-type-lists of the functions (8.3.5) are identical; and
> - when both names denote function templates, the signatures (14.5.6.1) are the same.

`::a` and `N::a` do not refer to members of the same namespace, so they do not denote the same variable.

Comment: The fact that they are usually connected by **or** in the standard seems to have made me stray. Thank you!!